# How to wrap rounded tcolorbox around lstinline?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I would like to have boxes around `\lstinline`. From another question I found the `\xpretocmd` trick with `\Colorbox`, but I cannot manage to apply it with `\tcbox`. Is there a way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setmonofont{inconsolata}

\lstset{
    language=c++,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{black!40!black},
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=true,
    tabsize=3,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip=2pt,
    belowskip=2pt,
    framexleftmargin=2pt,
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8
}

\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\lstinline{\Colorbox{MyGray}\bgroup\appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\CD}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}

\tcbset{on line,
        boxsep=3pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=white,colback=MyGray,
        highlight math style={enhanced}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Highlight}

There is a \CD{for} loop. It uses a \CD{std::vector}. A variable is named \CD{i} and \CD{j} is used. \tcbox{variable}, \tcbox{i}, \tcbox{j}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` documentation has an example on p. 21 which shows how to use `\NewTotalTCBox` with `\lstinline`. Adapted to your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstset{
    language=c++,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{black!40!black},
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=true,
    tabsize=3,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip=2pt,
    belowskip=2pt,
    framexleftmargin=2pt,
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8
}

\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\NewTotalTCBox{\CD}{v}{verbatim,colback=MyGray}{\lstinline[]^#1^}


\tcbset{on line,
        boxsep=3pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=white,colback=MyGray,
        highlight math style={enhanced}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Highlight}

There is a \CD{for} loop. It uses a \CD{std::vector}. A variable is named \CD{i} and \CD{j} is used. \tcbox{variable}, \tcbox{i}, \tcbox{j}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `\lstinline` wants the argument between two symbols, like `\lstinline!for!`, where `!` is not in the argument. So what you want your command to do is `\Colorbox{MyGray}{\lstinline!for!}` where `for` is the argument (if I understand your question right). To make that command you first need to expand the argument and then `\lstinline`. So one of

```
\newcommand\CD[1]{\Colorbox{MyGray}{\expandafter\lstinline\expandafter!#1!}}
\newcommand\CDa[1]{\Colorbox{MyGray}{\expandafter\lstinline#1}}
```

They are called with or without a symbol. So the following code seems to work here

```
\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

%%\makeatletter
%%\xpretocmd\lstinline{\Colorbox{MyGray}\bgroup\appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup}}{}{}
%%\makeatother

%%\newcommand{\CD}[1]{\lstinline#1}

\newcommand\CD[1]{\Colorbox{MyGray}{\expandafter\lstinline\expandafter!#1!}}
\newcommand\CDa[1]{\Colorbox{MyGray}{\expandafter\lstinline#1}}

\tcbset{on line,
        boxsep=3pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=white,colback=MyGray,
        highlight math style={enhanced}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Highlight}

Test \Colorbox{MyGray}{\lstinline!for!} or \CD{for} or \CDa{!for!} or \CDa{$for$}

\end{document}
```